# Applying Page Numbers during page break in Netsuite

Tags: pdf, netsuite, page-break

I am working on a Netsuite Advanced PDF template, which requires a page break after a few pages to include a separate header, can we make the total pages to be the count before the page break, and start counting from 1 after the page break?

Example total page count:12
I need a page break after 8 pages

Page 1 of 8,
Page 2 of 8,
Page 3 of 8,
Page 4 of 8,
Page 5 of 8,
Page 6 of 8,
Page 7 of 8,
Page 8 of 8,
After PBR tag
Page 1 of 4,
Page 2 of 4,
Page 3 of 4,
Page 4 of 4

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by separating the two sections into separate PDF tags and then wrapping them both in a PDFSET tag.

```
<pdfset>
    <pdf>
        ...
    </pdf>
    <pdf>
        ...
    </pdf>
</pdfset>
```

Alternatively, you can simplify this by creating the PDFs separately and saving to the file cabinet, then link to them within the PDFSET:

```
<pdfset>
    <pdf src="{{link_to_pdf_1}}"></pdf>
    <pdf src="{{link_to_pdf_2}}"></pdf>
</pdfset>
```

Note that with this second option, the PDF files need to be marked as "Available Without Login" for them to be accessible to the PDF generator.  You'll need to determine for yourself whether that's acceptable security-wise for your use case.